# Find the interval of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^∞ sin(\frac{1}{n}) tan(\frac{1}{n})x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the interval of convergence for:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \sin(\frac{1}{n})\tan(\frac{1}{n})x^n$$

I have no idea how to do this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For large $n$, $\sin(1/n)\sim \tan(1/n) \sim 1/n$.  Use the ratio test with this in mind.

Comment: @mjqxxxx can we also assume that for large n, sin(1/n+1) ~ tan(1/n+1) ~ 1/n+1? If I use both of these assumptions, I'll get -1<x<1 as my interval of convergence

Answer (score 1):

In this case,
I think the root test
is easier.

$  (\sin(\frac{1}{n})\tan(\frac{1}{n})x^n)^{1/n}
\approx \frac{x}{n^{2/n}}
\approx x
$
since
$n^{1/n} \to 1$.

For $x=1$,
the terms approach
$\frac1{n^2}$
so the sum converges.

Answer (score 0):

Here $a_n=\sin(\frac{1}{n})\tan(\frac{1}{n})x^n$

So 
\begin{align*}
\Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big|&=\Big|\frac{\sin\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)\tan\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)x^{n+1}}{\sin\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)\tan\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)x^n}\Big|\\
&=\Big|\frac{\sin\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)}{\frac{1}{n+1}}\frac{\tan\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)}{\frac{1}{n+1}}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sin\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\tan\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)}x|\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}|x|
\end{align*}

Therefore rate of convergence = $-1<x<1$

You also need to check at the endpoints.